# ¿Se considera correcto el siguiente uso de "return 0;"?

Tags: c

Dentro de un curso de programación en lenguaje C que estoy tomando, entre en la sección de bucles (while, do-while, for, etc..).

Y dentro de una de las practicas tenia como meta lograr que en el ultimo `printf` en el cual imprime los números introducidos por el usuario, al llegar al ultimo numero, lo imprima con un punto final.

[image: En el ultimo numero de la lista se imprime con un punto final.]

Pero necesitaba encontrar la manera de que al llegar a esa parte del bucle y se cumpliera la condición del if, el programa se detuviera. Así que considere, ya que era la parte final del programa, colocar el `return 0;` para detenerlo al cumplirse el if.

**¿Lo que hice, aunque si funciono, se considera correcto? y de lo contrario ¿como hacerlo de la manera correcta?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMITE 10

int main() {
int tabla[LIMITE], total, suma = 0, i = 0;

  do {
      printf("¿Cuantos numeros quieres sumar (entre 0 y %d)?: ", LIMITE);
      scanf("%d", &total);

      if (total < 0 || total > LIMITE)
          printf("Error. Debes introducir un numero entre 0 y %d.\n\n", LIMITE);

     } while (total < 0 || total > LIMITE);

  while (i < total) {
      printf("\nIntroduce un numero: ");
      scanf("%d", &tabla[i]);
      suma += tabla[i];
      i++;
  }

  printf("La suma de los numeros: ");

  i = 0;
  while (i < total){

      if (i + 1 == total) {
          printf(" %d. es %d", tabla[i], suma);
          return 0;
      }

      printf(" %d,", tabla[i]);
      i++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo habría usado `break` en vez de `return 0`.

Si bien es cierto que con `return` abandonas la función `main` y, con ello, el programa finaliza, con `break` el código quedaría más natural ya que realmente te interesa no es abandonar el `main` sino únicamente el bucle... que no haya más código después del bucle es algo secundario.

Así pues, lo dicho, yo sustituiría `return 0` por `break`:

```
if (i + 1 == total) {
    printf(" %d. es %d", tabla[i], suma);
    break;
}
```

E incluso podría quedar algo más limpio el código si el `printf` se moviese fuera del bucle. Para gustos los colores:

```
while (i < total){

    if (i + 1 == total) break;

    printf(" %d,", tabla[i]);
    i++;
}

printf(" %d. es %d", tabla[i], suma);
```

Comment: ¿Entonces la función break no es propia de switch?, ya que pues, solo la había utilizado en tales casos.

Comment: @JeremyJasiel `break` no es una función sino una instrucción y funciona con `switch`, `while`, `do-while`  y `for`